# Python - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'y'

Tags: python

```
fileRef = open(the_file, "r")    # opening file to be read
```

I got the following error :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'y'
```

Comment: If `the_file` is `'y'`  and no file with this name exists, you will get this error.

Comment: I suppose `'y'` is the name of the file, the error itself tells what's wrong. `"There is no 'y'"`

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not trying to be rude or anything, but the error message is definitely very clear. The error itself `FileNotFoundError` means that a file you requested was not found in the location you told the program to look. If I were to have a folder with the files `a`, `b` and `c` in it, and I asked to open `y`, I would expect this error. Because `y` is not `a`, `b` or `c`.

Assuming from the code you provided the value of `the_file` is `"y"` then you're asking Python to look in the location around where you execute the program from (I'm assuming Python behaves this way). If you do in fact have a file called `y` then I suggest you move it to the location where you want to execute from or move to that location and execute the Python code (whichever best suits your needs).